# Nginx with proxypass on Nextjs app and NextAuth redirectme to localhost

Tags: nginx, next.js, reverse-proxy, next-auth

I always worked in localhost with my app. Now I moved the app in a dev environment where I have Nginx webserver with proxy pass configuration.

When I first start the app, still in dev mode, i get the following warning on the consolle

```
https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#nextauth_url
[next-auth][warn][NEXTAUTH_URL]
```

I have a env NEXTAUTH_URL variable with my domain https:///subdomain.example.com

As I said I have also NextAuth with email Provider that locally works fine but now each time I try to login it redirectme to `http://localhost:port` returning Access Denied

I'm not able to understand if it is a Nextjs issue or Nginx

Here is my sites-available from nginx

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

#    root /usr/share/example.com/html; #solo per file statici
#    index index.html; #solo per file statici

    server_name *.example.com;

    location / {
#            try_files $uri $uri/ =404; #solo per file statici
#                proxy_set_header Host $host;
#                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

   }
}
```

I also have configured `site: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL` inside [...nextauth].js

Many thanks fo any help

**--------UPDATE--------**

Finally I solved it.

It was an issue with next.config.js
The NEXTAUTH_URL inside next.config.js doesn't work. I have placed an env file in the root folder with NEXTAUTH_URL declared and everithing is solved now.

I don't still understand why next.config.js doesn't work. I hope someone can explain

Comment: Is your app listening on `8000`? Did you run `netstat -tulpn | grep 8000` to see? Also check if nginx is up and if there are errors, check its error log.

Comment: yes it is. When I first try to access the app with my subdomain.example.com I reach the right page. NextAuth redirectme to signinpage. When I try to login it fail and redirectme to localhost